# How many layers of a pretrained model shoud be frozen?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cnn, machine-learning-model, transfer-learning

I am following a transfer learning example where the blogger has frozen the first 20 layers of MobileNet. My question is, is there any rule of thumb for how many layers should be frozen? What is the best practice?

Answer (score -1):

It is not the number of layers that matter, but the number of trainable parameters. This number should definitely be greater compared to the size of training data you have, and by size I mean: (number of samples)X(number of features). This number should **at least** be an order of magnitude greater compared to trainable parameters or lower: if your data set has size 1000, your trainable parameters should be 100 or less.

Comment: Contradiction spotted: first you said 'This number (of trainable parameters) should definitely be greater compared to the size of training data', but then your example said the opposite: 'if your data set has size 1000, your trainable parameters should be 100 or less'.

Comment: Besides, can you put some references to this claim?